# Comparison of csv files in perl

Tags: perl, csv

I have 10-15 csv files that consist of id, index, and fragment.

I want to compare only fragment columns of each file with others it should give unique entries. But in output it should also print the Id (columns: fragment, id_file1, file2(1 if present or 0), id_file2, file 2(1 if present or 0) etc.)

I got the code but it's for a file containing of single columns only. In this code, the output file contains only the fragment columns but is not giving 1 or 0, which means that the remaining columns are blank.

### File 1

```
Id  Index Fragment
11    A        abc  
12    B        pqr 
13    D        asd
```

### File 2

```
Id  Index Fragment    
12    E       pol
15    G       pqr   
17    H       trw
```

### Output:

```
Fragment Id_file1 File_1 Id_file_2 File_2
abc         11        1               0
pqr         12        1     15        1     
asd         13        1               0     
pol                   0     12        1
trw                   0     17        1
```

code

```
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use Text::CSV_XS;

use constant {
    FILE_1  => "1.csv",
    FILE_2  => "2.csv",
    FILE_3  => "3.csv",
};

my %hash;
#
# Load the Hash with value from File #1
#
open my $file1_fh, "<", FILE_1;
while ( my $value = <$file1_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash{$value}++;
}
close $file1_fh;
#
# Add File #2 to the Hash
#
open my $file2_fh, "<", FILE_2;
while ( my $value = <$file2_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash{$value} += 10;   # if the key already exists, the value will now be 11
                           # if it did not exist, the value will be 10
}
close $file2_fh;

open my $file3_fh, "<", FILE_3;
while ( my $value = <$file3_fh> ) {
    chomp $value;
    $hash{$value} += 100;
}
close $file3_fh;

for my $k ( sort keys %hash ) 
{   if ($hash{$k} == 1) { # only in file 1
        say "$k\t0\t0\t1";
    }
    elsif ($hash{$k} == 10) { # only in file 2
        say "$k\t0\t1\t0";
    }
    elsif ($hash{$k} == 100) { # only in file 2
        say "$k\t1\t0\t0";
    }
    else { # in both file 1 and file 2
        say "$k\t1\t1\t1";
    }
}

open (OUT, ">final.csv") or die "Cannot open OUT for writing \n";
$, = " \n";
print OUT "fragment\t1\t2\t3 \n";
print OUT (sort keys %hash);
close OUT;
```

Comment: You read the contents of `FILE_1`, `FILE_3`, and `FILE_3`, but show the contents of `File 1` and `File 2`. Your count shows the `id` and the count only for `File_1` and `File_2`. What is the real situation?

Comment: actually this script was for 2 files, i forgot to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you'll need to alter your data structure as you want to store information about the file, the fragment, and the ID of the fragment. Since the ID changes from file to file, you'll want to store the ID that corresponds to a specific file.

The previous script used a simple method to keep track of which files contained which fragments. This script will need to be a little more complex as we're pulling more data from the files and outputting it in a different way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# put our files in an array
my @files = ('1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv');

my %hash;
#
# Load the Hash with value from File #1
#
# since we're doing the same parsing to each file,
# let's save ourselves some typing and run the same code
# on each file
for my $f (@files) {
    open my $fh, "<", $f or die "Could not open $f: $!";
    while (my $val = <$fh>) {
        # skip the first line
        next if $. == 1;
        chomp $val;
        # split the line by the tabs
        my ($id, $ix, $frag) = split(/\t/, $val);
        # store the data in a hash of hashes of hashes
        # keys are the fragment, then the file name
        # I've stored the index and the id, but obviously
        # you can alter this if you have files of a different format
        # and/or want to save different data.
        $hash{$frag}{$f} = { ix => $ix, id => $id };
    }
}
```

The data structure created now allows us to access the information about each fragment in the following manner:

```
# get the ID of the fragment $x in 2.csv
say $hash{$x}{"2.csv"}{id};

# check if fragment $y exists in 3.csv, and print the index if so
if ( $hash{$y}{"3.csv"} ) {
   say $hash{$y}{"3.csv"}{ix};
}
```

OK, back to the script:

```
#set up the output file
my $out;
open ($out, ">final.csv") or die "Cannot open final.csv for writing \n";
# print out a header row
# map applies the code within the brackets to every element of @files,
# so in this case, we're printing out "ID_<array element> \t <array element >"
# for every file in our list
# the join joins together items following it using the string "\t" 
print { $out } join("\t", "Fragment", map { "ID_$_\t$_" } @files) . "\n";

# now, output our data
# $frag is the fragment
for my $frag ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print { $out } "$frag\t";
#   check which files it appears in
    foreach (@files) {
        # if it exists in that file, print out the ID and '1'
        if ( $hash{$frag}{$_} ) {
            print { $out } $hash{$frag}{$_}{id} . "\t1\t";
        }
        else {
            # print nothing in the ID column, and 0 in the file column
            print { $out } "\t0\t";
        }
    }
    print $out "\n";
}
close $out;
```

Comment: Its working, but i am not able to get fragment heading, heading started with id_file1, file1, id_file2, file2. Also id_file columns are empty (ids are not able to printing). it only printing fragments , and 1 or 0. Means output is like id_file1(printing fragment column), file1(empty), id_file2(1 or 0), file2(empty), without heading(1 or 0).

Comment: I edited the code as I forgot to add the 'Fragment' column header -- make sure you have the most up to date version.

Comment: If there seems to be missing information, first check that the data you want is present in `%hash` -- use `Data::Dumper` or `Data::Dump` to print out the data structure and check you are getting the IDs.

Comment: If you read my answer, you'll see that the code with $x and $y was meant as an example, not just to be blindly pasted into your script. Please read the comments I've written and you should be able to solve any issues that are remaining.

Comment: sorry i was getting delay messages. Got it. Thank you so much

Comment: Great! Have a play around with printing out different pieces of data from the data structure so then you'll be more confident experimenting with different things in future scripts.

Comment: @i am alien: sorry but still i am not getting output. its giving only 1 row(fragment- blank, id_file1-id, file_1-index, id_file2-fragment, file_2- 1 or 0 etc.)

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Are you still having a problem? If so, have you tried dumping the data structure `%hash` to make sure it is populated? i.e. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%hash);`

Comment: nope. i did some modification and its working. no need to use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%hash);. thank you

Answer (score 0):

i would do the following:

1. put files to parse into an array (either directly at file scope or by read the cmd args) since it is no option to duplicate the code for each file.
   `my @files = ( "file1", "file2", "file3");`
2. loop over this list, open each file and add its fragmentsto a hash with string as key and a list of structures that point to file it occurs and its index

So that the hash looks like this at the end:

```
%hash = (
  "abc"  => [ {fileIdx => 0, id => 11, line => 1, ind => "A"} ] ,
  "pqr"  => [ {fileIdx => 0, id => 12, line => 2, ind => "B"}, 
              {fileIdx => 1, id => 15, line => 2, ind => "G"}]
)
```

3. All you have to done after that is simply iterate over the hash and iterate ofer the structs of the list for each key.